# Must a client connect directly to the endorsers, or can it proxy via any peer?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I'm reading the [Hyperledger Fabric Architecture Explained](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arch-deep-dive.html) document.

I understand that when a client wants to invoke a transaction, it must get that transaction endorsed, and then send it to the ordering service.

I'm confused about if the client must connect directly to the endorsers and orderers, or whether it can just connect to an available peer and have the proposal be forwarded to the necessary nodes.

For the ordering service, this is [explained clearly](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arch-deep-dive.html#the-submitting-client-collects-an-endorsement-for-a-transaction-and-broadcasts-it-through-ordering-service):

> If the client does not have capability of invoking ordering service directly, it may proxy its broadcast through some peer of its choice.

However for the endorsers, it's [not so clear](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arch-deep-dive.html#client):

> To invoke a transaction, the client sends a `PROPOSE` message to a set of endorsing peers of its choice (possibly not at the same time - see Sections 2.1.2. and 2.3.). The set of endorsing peers for a given `chaincodeID` is made available to client via peer, which in turn knows the set of endorsing peers from endorsement policy

I understand a client must send a `PROPOSE` message to the endorsing peers. But what does it mean by "*The set of endorsing peers for a given `chaincodeID` is made available to client via peer*"? Does it mean "via **any** peer", thus implying the client does not have to connect directly to the endorsers? Or must the client connect directly to the endorser peers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we need to update the architecture doc you reference to match the current implementation in Hyperledger Fabric v1.0.x and the upcoming v1.1.0.

The client MUST send transactions directly to the orderer and must directly communicate with all endorsing peers.  It cannot "proxy" any of these calls through a peer in the current implementation.

Typically the client will get the information about which peers/orgs are required to endorse a specific chaincode through an out of band mechanism.